# WordPress with PDF error "Unexpected server response (204) "

Tags: wordpress, pdf, embed, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-plugin-creation

i was trying to embed PDF reader in my WordPress website visitors can read and and take print of PDF.
i did use many WordPress  plugins but i am getting same error again and again "Unexpected server response (204)" i am using premium WordPress theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see this error message, do you have a download manager installed on your browser? This sometimes causes problems - maybe take a look at your extensions, and also try on a different browser to see if that works. If it does, it seems likely to be limited to your original browser.
Disabling the download manager should help.
you can use download manager without intercepting PDF